# how to ping guest xp from host ubuntu in virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, penetration-testing

I have a ubuntu in my lap top and install virtualbox. I install an xp as guest in vbox.
I want to have access to guest from host for penetration usage.

@1st try: the guest uses bridge network with ip 192.168.1.103 (assigned static).
I can not access guest form host, when I ping the guest, loosing all packages.

```
ping 192.168.1.103
```

But I can access host form guest, when I ping the host.

```
ping 192.168.1.101
```

@2nd try: the guest uses an NAT and a Host-Only network.
same as above host can not access the guest:

```
ping 192.168.56.103
```

but guest can access the host:

```
ping 192.168.56.1
```

who can I access the guest from host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can ping host from the guest, it tells that the connection is working ok both ways (response comes back ok). The problem probably is that XP has not been configured to answer to ping requests so it's silently discarding them. You need to change the settings of the firewall to allow answers to ping.

See for example http://kb.iu.edu/data/aopy.html for details how to enable ping service in different Windows versions with the default firewall.

Comment: Thanx, This is my answer. I disabled winxp(the guest) firewall and now I can ping the the guest from host in both bridge mode and host-only mod